# Bananagrams decision problem - computational complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, combinatorics, board-games

I've been playing Bananagrams recently, and have begun to wonder about the math behind it from a computational perspective.  I've tried to formalize the problem as a decision problem below.

Loosely formal definition:
Given a finite set (alphabet) **$A$**  of letters, a finite set (dictionary) **$D \subset$(Set of all finite sequences of elements of $A$**), and a multiset (bag) **$B$** of letters such that **$B = (A, m), m: A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$**, decide whether a valid grid-aligned arrangement exists for **$(A, D, B)$**.

A "valid grid-aligned arrangement" is a satisfying bananagrams combination of letters - I'm not sure the best way to formalize this but in essence a tuple $(A, D, B)$ has a valid grid-aligned arrangement if: each element $w\in A$ is placed at some coordinates on an infinite grid $m(w)$ times, the grid contains only one connected component of adjacent elements $w\in B$, and for each axis-aligned sequence $s$ of (more than 1) letters $w\in B$, read left-to-right or top-to-bottom, $s\in D$.

Where does this problem fall in the computational complexity hierarchy?
My intuition is that this is at least NP-HARD, as it loosely resembles the knapsack problem or the subset-sum problem, but does the geometric aspect make this any more difficult?

Bonus question, what about the problem of optimizing the rectangular area of the resulting grid?  i.e. deciding whether a valid arrangement exists with rectangular grid area $\leq n$ for some $n\in Z$.

(I asked this question in Mathematics Stack Exchange before I knew there was a CS SE, apologies if reposting is bad etiquette).